# What does "to the flood of..." mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "to the flood of..." mean? Does it mean "Among many..."

> This might not be a fair comment since it’s only been five days since Apple Card debuted. But the word on the financial street is none too encouraging. To the flood of credit cards issued by banking and financial institutions are those from tech firms such as PayPal, Square and Venmo (which is owned by PayPal). And now, Apple.

Source: https://www.ibtimes.com/samsung-google-release-own-credit-cards-after-apple-card-experts-say-no-2780975

Comment: It looks to me like a verb--probably *added*--has been accidentally omitted after *are*: cards from tech firms, and now Apple, have been added to the 'flood' (vast quantity) of cards from banking and financial institutions.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like incorrect grammar to me. I wonder if the author meant to say "Within the flood of..." or something similar.

The author is trying to convey a sense that there are so many credit cards issued nowadays that they resemble a flood, figuratively, and is using this imagery to introduce the point that technology companies are part of that flood of credit cards as well.

Therefore I'd say your "among many" is probably a fair replacement in this situation.